# Python `if` statement with `or` and `!=` condition

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
arr=input("enter a alphabet ")

if (arr=='a') or (arr=='c'):
    print("it is a or c")
else:
    print("not a or c")
```

code above gives desired output but code below does not why? please help

```
arr=input("enter a alphabet ")

if (arr!='a') or (arr!='c'):
    print("not a or c")
else:
    print("it is a or c")
```

Comment: Because you also need to switch to `and`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you need to replace `or` with `and`:

```
if not ((arr!='a') and (arr!='c')):
    print("it is a or c")
else:
    print("not a or c")
```